# Taxonomy Filed Issue while Copying Document Library Item Using CSOM in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, csom, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I am trying to Copy a Document having the Managed Metadata(Termsets) fields from one site collection to another site collection in SharePoint online using CSOM. The  Managed Metadata Fields are there in both the Document libraries with different Internal names but with same display name.  The Columns names are shown in below image. After Copying the document only **Topic** filed data is copied without any additional  coding.

[image: Taxonomyfiledar]

So I tried the below code  to copy  Managed Metadata(Termsets) fields after Uploading the file with internals names but the fields are not updating.

```
foreach (var stritem in Taxonomyfiledarray)
    {
    TaxonomyFieldValueCollection sourceValue = SourcelistItem[stritem.Source] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection; 
    string[] termValuesarrary;
    List<string> termValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue taxProductFieldValue in sourceValue)
    {
     termValues.Add(taxProductFieldValue.Label + "|" + taxProductFieldValue.TermGuid);
    }
    termValuesarrary = termValues.ToArray();
    string termValuesstring = string.Join(";", termValuesarrary);
    itemToCreate[stritem.Destination] = termValuesstring;
    }
    itemToCreate.Update();
```

Any Suggestion please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alok Kumar Gupta: Thanks for you guidance. Your guidance and the link[Setting a Managed Metadata Field with the Client Object Model](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.in/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-code-tips-setting.html) driven me to fix the issue.

```
                 foreach (var stritem in Taxonomyfiledarray)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            TaxonomyFieldValueCollection newtermValues = null;
                            Field field = fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(stritem.Destination);
                            destinationContext.Load(field);
                            destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
                            TaxonomyField txField = destinationContext.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
                            if (txField.AllowMultipleValues)
                            {
                                TaxonomyFieldValueCollection sourceValue = SourcelistItem[stritem.Source] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
                                string[] termValuesarrary;
                                List<string> termValues = new List<string>();
                                foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue taxProductFieldValue in sourceValue)
                                {
                                    // termValues.Add(taxProductFieldValue.Label + "|" + taxProductFieldValue.TermGuid);
                                    termValues.Add("-1;#" + taxProductFieldValue.Label + "|" + taxProductFieldValue.TermGuid);
                                }
                                termValuesarrary = termValues.ToArray();
                                string termValuesstring = string.Join(";#", termValuesarrary);
                                newtermValues = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(destinationContext, termValuesstring, txField);
                                txField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(itemToCreate, newtermValues);
                                itemToCreate.Update();
                                destinationContext.Load(itemToCreate);
                                destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            lbl_Error.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With assumption that both of the field use same TermSet, ExecuteQuery() is also called after this, try modified code:

```
foreach (var stritem in Taxonomyfiledarray)
{
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection sourceValue = SourcelistItem[stritem.Source] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection; 
string[] termValuesarrary;
List<string> termValues = new List<string>();
foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue taxProductFieldValue in sourceValue)
{
 termValues.Add("-1;#" + taxProductFieldValue.Label + "|" + taxProductFieldValue.TermGuid);
}
termValuesarrary = termValues.ToArray();
string termValuesstring = string.Join(";#", termValuesarrary);
itemToCreate[stritem.Destination] = termValuesstring;
}
itemToCreate.Update();
```

Comment: I tried the code but no change in the output .. And both of the fields use same TermSet

Comment: Have changes been made as per code above in line 8 & line 11. Please provide a sample value that you are trying to save. Also, pls confirm if both columns support multi selections?

Comment: Yes i changed the  code(added + sign after  "-1;#" ) and tested the code..

Comment: in join function as well, has it been changed to ";#" instead of ";"

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. Tested  with termValues.Add ("-1;#" + taxProductFieldValue.Label + "|" + taxProductFieldValue.TermGuid); and    string termValuesstring = string.Join(";#", termValuesarrary);. The out put has no effect only Topic field was copying

Comment: Is it possible to share screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56084/discussion-between-tarun-and-alok-kumar-gupta).

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. The issue was fixed. one up vote for your suggestion..